# Stop grunt from changing names on fonts

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman, grunt-usemin

So I'm in the situation where I have added a font to my `Yeoman` project. There is however a small problem. Whenever I run `grunt build` the file name of my font is changed, but it doesn't change in my `CSS` causing it to not work.

How can I fix this. I know that I have to look inside my `Gruntfile.js` but I have no idea where to look.

I already tried this:

```
// Performs rewrites based on rev and the useminPrepare configuration
usemin: {
  html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/{,*/}*.html'],
  css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/{,*/}*.css'],
  js: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/{,*/}*.js'],
  options: {
    assetsDirs: [
      '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public',
      '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/assets/images',
      '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/assets/fonts'
    ],
    // This is so we update image references in our ng-templates
    patterns: {
      js: [
        [/(assets\/images\/.*?\.(?:gif|jpeg|jpg|png|webp|svg))/gm, 'Update the JS to reference our revved images']
      ],
      css: [
        [/(assets\/images\/.*?\.(?:gif|jpeg|jpg|png|webp|svg))/gm, 'Update the CSS to reference our revved images']
      ]
    }
  }
},
```

Because I figured that if I could have it change the name in my CSS aswell it might work. But this doesn't really fix anything :-(

**UPDATE**

As requested here is the changes in the file name

Before:

```
ITCEDSCR.TTF
```

After

```
20118b60.ITCEDSCR.TTF
```

Comment: Can you show how exactly are the filenames change? <filename-before> and <filename-after>

Comment: According to https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp/issues/459 ->  // Performs rewrites based on rev and the useminPrepare configuration
    usemin: {
      options: {
        assetsDirs: [
          '<%%= config.dist %>',
          '<%%= config.dist %>/images',
          '<%%= config.dist %>/styles'
        ]
      },
      html: ['<%%= config.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
      css: ['<%%= config.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css']
    },
 so maybe just get rid of the fonts like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp/issues/459 ->

```
{
usemin: {
  options: {
    assetsDirs: [
      '<%%= config.dist %>',
      '<%%= config.dist %>/images',
      '<%%= config.dist %>/styles'
    ]
  },
  html: ['<%%= config.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
  css: ['<%%= config.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css']
}
}
```

Getting rid of the fonts should help I guess ?

Comment: No quite the correct answer. but helped me find a solution ^^ Thanks

Comment: Thanks for The vote! Yeah, I was sure that this won't be the exact solution but will help. :)

Answer (score 1):

### **ACTUAL SOLUTION !**

Thanks to Fer To's link I found a solution. It is kinda what he suggested, just had to change the code somewhere else as well.

This was my solution:

```
// Renames files for browser caching purposes
rev: {
  dist: {
    files: {
      src: [
        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/{,*/}*.js',
        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/{,*/}*.css',
        //'<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/assets/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
        //'<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/assets/fonts/*'
      ]
    }
  }
},

// Performs rewrites based on rev and the useminPrepare configuration
usemin: {
  html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/{,*/}*.html'],
  css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/{,*/}*.css'],
  js: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/{,*/}*.js'],
  options: {
    assetsDirs: [
      '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public',
      '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/assets/images'
    ],
    // This is so we update image references in our ng-templates
    patterns: {
      js: [
        [/(assets\/images\/.*?\.(?:gif|jpeg|jpg|png|webp|svg))/gm, 'Update the JS to reference our revved images']
      ]
    }
  }
},
```